# Changing opamp reference in linear power supply not giving expected results

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, power-electronics, bjt, linear-regulator

I am currently working to make a 30V 5A linear power supply and came up with this circuit so far. The circuit is supposed to give twice the reference voltage Vref.

[image]

This is the output voltage that I am getting which is the expected output.

[image]

But to be able to achieve 0V(or very close to 0V) at the output, I decided to take the output voltage as reference for the opamp supply voltage and the reference voltage(Vref). This is the circuit that I came up with to achieve this.

[image]

This is the output voltage that I am getting.

[image]

Changing the reference voltage(Vref) has a negligible effect on the output in the second case. In first circuit everything works as expected.

What mistake am I making here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How can you drive the ballast transistor with a voltage that can not be higher than 12 V (output of op-amp -> base of Q2) (first picture)?

EDIT : As @VictorTito pointed out, it is (arguably) better if the op amp power supply is "fixed" and not floating ... Ok, I haven't done a full stability study in this case. This may have "advantages"?

[image]

Seems that the emitter of Q2 would return to the ground, with some resistor between the Q3 base and Q2 collector. More effective. example of behavior, but not very linear.

[image]

Another example... more interesting and "linear".

[image]

Comment: My poor eyes thank you for using a white theme for your images.

Comment: What "color" would you like?

Comment: Antonio, circuits and plots with white background are much easier to visualize than with dark gray or black. I'm pretty sure there was no irony in @ElliotAlderson 's comment, but a sincere *"thank you"*. In fact, +1. ;)

Comment: No problem. I really understand. This remark was actually really very interesting. Maybe another color would be perhaps more appropriate and also maybe more user-friendly. :-)

Comment: Yes, I was seriously grateful. The usual thin dark green lines on a black background make my head hurt.

Comment: Sometimes also, some "pictures" are really unreadable ... It is perhaps a "recall" to our "old" times ... when we used a "blackboard" ... which is now "whiteboard" ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

I’m confused by your second circuit, and here is why:

1. The reference voltage of one volt has its negative connected to the output Vout. This will make your reference Vout + 1 Volt. The reference voltage will increase for each interaction of Vout + 1 volt until it reaches the maximum input voltage of 32 V minus any drop in the transistors Vbe and diode Vf. That is probably why you are getting Vout = 30 V.
2. The op-amp power supply V+ is 12 V plus Vout and V- is 12 V minus Vout. This will change the op-amp power supply for each interaction of Vout until the op-amp will have no effect in controlling Vout, wich will reach its maximum of 32 V minus any drop in the transistor Vbe and diode Vf.

Move the op-amp power supply back to 12 V and ground, not 12 V and Vout.

To reduce the 1 Volt reference voltage use a voltage divider.

Answer (score 1):

Using KVL for the Virtual Null, OA input, it appears as your Vref needs to be reversed.

Let Vo/2 = Vo-Vref not Vo+Vref